# What does [ ] on the end of a string variable do?

Tags: php

I have a piece of PHP that I am currently porting to Objective-C. Although there is one function that I cannot figure out what it does. More specifically the square brackets [ ] on the end of the $hash2 variable. $hash2 is a sha256 variable and $i == 64.

`$hash2[$i];`

Comment: Yet another trick or treat question.

Comment: Its an array, basics of every programming language. It contains more than one value.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use [array indexing on string values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), so $string[64] would get the 65th character (it is zero based)

Comment: This would make sense as when $hash2 is printed, it is a singular string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

That gets a value from an array based on index, as far as I'm aware. In pseudo-php:

```
$arr = array("example" => 1,
             "other" => 2,
             3 => 3);

$arr["example"] == 1; // true
$arr[3] == 3; // true
```

Strings are just character arrays, so operating this on a string would get the character at that index:

```
$string = "This is a sample";
echo $string[3]; // Prints "s".
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the value of the array at that offset. Some pseudo code:

```
array hash2;

hash2.get(i)
```

This is equivalent to the following PHP:

```
<?php

$hash2 = [];

echo $hash2[$i]

?>
```

---

If it is a string and not an array, you access the *i*th character within that string. This is because strings are internally character arrays (something you know from C).

```
<?php

$str = "Stackoverflow";

echo $str[2]; // t

?>
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid in the current stable version and the new syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score -1):

It means, the variable is considered as an array. The brackets let you define the index values.

You can learn more about that in the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

On the other hand, if the variable is indeed a string, then it will access the n-th character of that string.